iOS Dark Mode: Splash Screen Background Appears White
I'm encountering an issue specific to iOS. My app supports dark mode. Everything works fine except during the initial splash screen display. When launching the app on iOS, the splash screen background is briefly white, which disrupts the dark mode experience.
Here’s a video showing the issue:
Video issue
How can I configure the splash screen to respect dark mode on iOS or avoid the white background during app launch? Is this related to the default iOS launch screen setup or something CodenameOne specific?

Well, there is no behavior like this for a properly configured launch screen run from Xcode, so it sounds like a CodenameOne problem. (I am assuming that when you say "splash screen" you mean "launch screen"; note that the launch screen is not a splash screen.)

What you are seeing is the Launch Screen Storyboard. These are used to show the app instantly on the device without actually running it yet. We provide several ways to customize the story board including setting one of your own.
Probably the simplest thing you can do is provide a Launch.Background.png within the native iOS directory that would be black. It should solve the issue.
